# Twilio: Is it possible to start a SMS conversation between buisness and customer that starts on the Business Site?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Twilio
Is this possible? 
Overview: Client Requests SMS via Site -> SMS to Business Owner -> Owner Replies -> Customer Gets SMS

When a customer comes to our client's business site and enters their phone number I'd like to send a text to our client ( the biz owner or one of their employees ).

Here's the trick, I'd want the ability for our client to respond to that text message and have that responding SMS message to be sent to the customer who initiated the request.
Then the customer and our client can respond to each other in a conversation.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can build this from scratch by creating a service that maps bindings between the business owner and their customers. However, I would recommend using Twilio's [Proxy API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/proxy) which handles those bindings for you.

For example, ride hailing apps will use Proxy to create a temporary voice or SMS channel between a rider and driver.

When the user requests a follow up on your site, you should create a [Proxy session](https://www.twilio.com/docs/proxy/api/session).

To initiate an outbound SMS to a proxy participant (the business owner), follow [these instructions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/proxy/api/sending-messages).

I'd recommend a run through this [quickstart](https://www.twilio.com/docs/proxy/quickstart) as a first step.

Comment: Fantastic lead. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

How about this for ease.  You can use zapier or integromat to make this flow.

1. Have the customer request a text via entering their phone number via a form field on the website.  Google Forms, jotform, whatever you use.
2. Use a twilio integration from zapier or integromat to send the customer a text that says.  "Thanks for reaching out, staff will be right with you"
3. Zapier or Integromat either sends a text to your client with the details of who to text back OR you can post to slack and then have a slack notification go out to the channel.  That way if there is a team first one to see it can contact the customer.